# EJB as controller

Tags: java, ejb

When developing a Java EE application, it is possible to use EJBs as controllers?

The EJB container provides features such as lifecycle management, and concurrency control, Is it correct create a stateless EJB to be a controller and injects it into a ManagedBean?

Comment: There is nothing like not possible, but you may be re-inventing wheel to handle/manage HTTP protocol and User Session (if required).

Comment: So where it's in the MVC pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From EJB 3.0 and specially in 3.1, the EJB Beans become more and more POJOs thus the EJB concept blurs in favor of the more generic Managed Bean concept, inside the CDI. Even the `@EJB` annotation "competes" with `@Inject` and could eventually be replaced by it.

So in CDI, a controller can be a managed bean and take advantage of the Java EE server features like lifecycle management and such.